# data binding to asp.net tree view

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have City database show as below ,

```
City
-----
CityName
CountryName
```

I want  to bind this data to asp.net Tree View

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>
```

Just like ,

```
CountryName1 
    CityName1
    CityName2
    CityName3
CountryName2
    CityName4
    CityName5
    CityName6
```

I use `linq` data source to bind data ,

```
TreeView1.DataSource = DB.Cities.ToList();
TreeView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139479/how-to-add-root-node-in-tree-view-dynamically-using-asp-net/16139564?noredirect=1#comment23057324_16139564 refer this

Comment: Thanks , that's useful 4 me !

Answer (score 0):

try editing from design which is easier..
After binding with a datasource click on `Edit Treenode data binding`  and categorize it in any hierarchy format by specifying the appropriate root and child nodes...