# OnSelectedNodeChanged event in asp.net treeview doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

Here is my code in `.aspx` ,

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server"
 OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged"
 ImageSet="Arrows" >
</asp:TreeView>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="selectedNode"></asp:TextBox>
```

In my `.cs` file ,

```
 protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedNode.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value;
}
```

But , `OnSelectedNodeChanged` event doesn't work , I want to know why .

I bind the nodes dynamically . I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139479/how-to-add-root-node-in-tree-view-dynamically-using-asp-net/16139564?noredirect=1#comment23057324_16139564) .

Comment: I bind the nodes dynamically :) I used this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139479/how-to-add-root-node-in-tree-view-dynamically-using-asp-net/16139564?noredirect=1#comment23057324_16139564

Comment: @andy , yes , its not firing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right it will not work because in the link it is written

```
 root.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
```

Instead of it write //use .Select

```
  root.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
```

It will work.

```
TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand
Toggles the node between expanded and collapsed. Raises the TreeNodeExpanded event or the TreeNodeCollapsed event, as appropriate.

TreeNodeSelectAction.None
Raises no events when a node is selected.

TreeNodeSelectAction.Select 
Raises the SelectedNodeChanged event when a node is selected.

TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand
Raises both the SelectedNodeChanged and TreeNodeExpanded events when a node is selected. Nodes are only expanded, never collapsed.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but another reason for the OnSelectedNodeChanged not to fire is if you have the NavigateURL value set for the given node.
There is a trick you could use though. Remove the NavigateURL property and set the node "Value" property to the url you want to link to and then in the OnSelectedNodeChanged event fire in the code behind, redirect to the url from the SelectedNode.Value property.

HTH

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. When I remove NavigateURL for the nodes when they are dynamically generated, the OnSelectedNodeChanged event fires.